# Java Listing files in directory

Tags: java, javascript, applet, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to get a list of all mp3 files in a directory (the subdir named music in the directory of the applet) so that I then can their names in a JavaScript function to push them into an array.

Everything works, but the listing process... It only return the very first mp3 file in the directory, not the other ones...

This is my code

JAVA:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Applet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void init() {
        File[] lib = getFiles(new File((getCodeBase() + File.separator + "music").substring(6)));
        for (File s:lib) {
            if (s.getName().substring(s.getName().length() - 3).equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")) {
                try {getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:addSong('"+s.getName()+"')"));}
                catch (MalformedURLException me) {}
            }
        }
        try {getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:init()"));}
        catch (MalformedURLException me) {}
    }
    public File[] getFiles(File dir) {
        return dir.listFiles();
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function addSong(s) {
    // Adding to array
    window.songs.push("music/" + s);
    // Debug message
    alert(s);
}

function init() {
// Random code to initialze music player
// getting and listing values from "songs" which got content form addSong()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried executing this applet from another host than the one which serves this applet? There's no way you can access files on the server using `new File()`.

Comment: @JBNizet  I was about to say the same thing, but since you already said it, I'll just up-vote the comment as the first sensible thing offered in reply.

Comment: *"I'm trying this locally"*  So what?  Get it to work locally, and it will *still* fail in production.  The entire approach needs to be changed (and possibly the task abandoned).

Comment: It is only supposed to work locally.

Comment: Then why on earth are you coding an applet?  An applet really only makes sense when it is being deployed to people over a network or the internet.  BTW - this applet will need to be digitally signed, a plain application would not.

Comment: No need to sign it, it works. I am coding an applet to be able to list mp3 fiels in a folder on my computer (JavaScript can not do this (only with ActiveXObject in IE))

Comment: 1) Code an application.  Trust [me](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers), an applet will ***not*** work once it is in HTML (unless signed and trusted). 2) An application is easier to both develop and run.  3) Note also a) The subtle hint provided by the link in this comment.  I have **extensive** experience with applets.  b) Please prefix comments with @PersonName, to ensure they are notified of the comment.  I only noticed these comments since I happened to drop back by, and checked for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list(recursively) all files(with .mp3 extension) in a given directory I have this following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FileLister {

    private List<File> getFileList(File startingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = startingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            result.add(file); 
            if (!file.isFile()) {               
                List<File> deeperList = getFileList(file);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        for(File file : new FileLister().getFileList(new File("D:\\Music"))){
            if(file.getName().contains(".")) {
                String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf("."), file.getName().length());
                if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".mp3")) {
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work on a live server.  `File` objects ***always*** point to the client file system.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks. It was unknown to me. I have up-voted it. Is there anyway to list files of server?

Comment: Only with help from the server itself.  E.G. some servers are insecure, and will provide an HTML table or list of files in a directory.  An applet might parse that, but it is fragile to changes by the server.  Alternately the server side folks might provide a servlet (PHP, ASP etc.) that the applet can connect to in order to get a simpler list.  Presumably this server-side functionality would have checks to ensure the applet only interrogates for the content of specifically allowed directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have made slight changes in your code. Check it out. This should resolve your issue:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Applet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        File[] lib = getMP3Files("E:/Music/BollywoodMusic"); // pass your directory name here
        for(File s:lib) {
            try { getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:addSong('"+s.getName()+"')")); } catch(MalformedURLException me) {}
        }

        try {getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:init()"));}
        catch (MalformedURLException me) {}
    }

    public static File[] getMP3Files(String directoryName) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        return directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
                return fileName.endsWith(".mp3"); } });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (on eclipse) and it works fine, be sure u putted the files in the right directory

and i can't get why u are using `.substring(6)`

Comment: This will not work on a live server.  `File` objects ***always*** point to the client file system.